# Ребят Возник вопрос `Uncaught TypeError: x is not a function хотя $(document).ready` прописан

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table

Привет ребят, создаю редактируемую таблицу подсчета стоимости товара, и вот не как не могу получить функцию из `onclick()` короче код

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script >
  $(document).ready (function x(){
    var x = $('#x1').text();
    var y = $('#y1').text();
    $('#sum1').text(x*y);

  });
  </script>
<title>Редактировать данные в таблице</title>

<style>
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
td,th {
border:2px solid #ccc;
padding:0;
}
td p {
margin:0;
padding:2px 4px;
}
td p:focus {outline:1px solid #5D90FE;}
</style>
</head>

<body >
<br><br><br>
<table id="example" contenteditable="true">
  <tr contenteditable="false"> <th>Номер</th> <th>Название</th> <th>Цена</th><th>Количество</th><th>Сумма</th> </tr>
        <tr> <td>10</td> <td>01.07.2013</td> <td id="x1">2</td>  <td id="y1">2</td> <td id="sum1">0</td> <td><button onclick="x()"  contenteditable="false"id="button1">Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
      <tr> <td>20</td> <td>02.07.2013</td> <td id="x2">0</td>  <td id="y2">0</td> <td>0</td> <td><button contenteditable="false" onclick="" >Подсчитать</button></td></tr>
        <tr> <td>30</td> <td>03.07.2013</td> <td>0</td>  <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td><button >Подсчитать</button contenteditable="false"></td></tr>
      <tr> <td>40</td> <td>04.07.2013</td> <td>0</td>  <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td><button >Подсчитать</button contenteditable="false"></td></tr>
        <tr> <td>50</td> <td>05.07.2013</td> <td>0</td>  <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td><button >Подсчитать</button contenteditable="false"></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

маюсь уже так 4 дня, переносил во все дырки куда только можно и в head и за body и т.д

Comment: Как вызываете? Весь код, пожалуйста, потому как вариант рабочий, если не считать каких-то кавычек. Ошибка в вызове скорее всего

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, Не стоит оборачивать в сниппет любой js код. В данном случае стоило оставить его обычным блоком кода, либо добавить разметку, чтобы получился полноценный пример.

Comment: А если заменить `$(document).ready (function x(){` на `$(document).ready(function() {` ?

Comment: Уберите `$(document).ready (` и `)` в конце (в `});`), и код заработает. Но, конечно, только для первой кнопки.

Comment: И немного по самому коду. 1. Использование `onclick`в HTML считается плохой практикой. Используйте `addEventListener`. 2. Что делает `contenteditable="false` в закрывающем теге `</button>` - для меня загадка. 3. Чтобы работало для всех кнопок, стоит переходить с ID на классы. 4. Названия переменным и функциям нужно давать такие, чтобы по ним было понятно за что переменная/функция отвечает.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже исправил,